# Java class interface design question

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class (MiddleMan) talks to a system and this talk is initialized by the MiddleMan's clients.

If a 'talk' is successfully completed, MiddleMan will generate a token and return it to its client.

The class design I have at the moment is like below:

```
class MiddleMan{
    private String token = null;
    private String param1;
    private String param2;
    private String amount;

    boolean isTalkSuccessful = false;

    public MiddleMan(String param1, String param2){
    this.amount = amount;
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
    }

    public String talk() throws ValidationException{

      //a private method validates param1 and param2
    validateParameters();

     //talk to backend system;
    isTalkSuccessful = talkToSystem();


    }

    Private void validateParameters() throws ValidationException {

    }

    private boolen talkToSystem(){

    }


    public boolean isTalkSuccessful(){
      return isTalkSuccessful;
    }

    public String getToken() throws Exception{
       if(isTalkSuccessful()){
          return token;
      }else{
        throw new Exception("cannot return token because talk is not  successful");
      }

     }



}
```

Does this look right to you? How would you refactor it?

Comment: What looks at `isTalkSuccessful`? What does the client code that uses this class look like?

Comment: @Laurence, a client of middle man checks if "talk" is successful by calling isTalkSuccessful(). Then the client calls getToken() to get token. If the client calls this method without checking if isTalkSuccessful() returns true (and isTalkSuccessful() returns false), then an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Oops. I hadn't noticed the scrollbar, so I didn't see those other methods.

Comment: BTW: in comments use backticks to format as code (works in questions/answers too).

Comment: @Laurence. That is ok. My question could have been clearer too. Thanks for the tip. I was trying <code> in comment, didn't work out well. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From where the `amount` come into play. It's not in the list of instance variables, neither it's there in the constructor argument. You need to fix this in your snippet to avoid confusion.
2. The validation of parameters should be done in the constructor. In case the parameters are not valid throw some appropriate exception from the constructor. `talk()` method should not validate, as its name is suggesting.
3. I can see you are calling `isTalkSuccessful()` method in your `getToken()`. I am assuming you want client to check this before calling `getToken()` to avoid exception. Isn't it? And you have your check in place just in case client doesn't call `isTalkSuccessful()`. Correct? So, if avoiding the exception is the whole point, why not just don't throw any exception. Lets get rid of that public method `isTalkSuccessful()` and let the client call `getToken()`. In your `getToken()` method check the private field `isTalkSuccessful` and if it's false return `null`. Why not?
4. Do you really need `setToken()`? Who will invoke it?

Comment: 1) fixed. 2)Agree. 3)is 'return null' the general practice? 4)Removed.

Comment: @sarahTheButterFly: Good question. Okay I would suggest you to throw an exception but not from `getToken()` but from `talk()` method. And I think returning `null` in `getToken()` is fair enough. Why? Well suppose client never invoked `talk()` method and invoked `getToken()`. In this case, I suppose returning `null` make more sense. You should clearly document that, though. What say you?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are calling talk() first and then generating the token by calling getToken():

Don't you need to set the `token` variable? It is initialized with a null value, and is never modified. I guess you need to set `token` to whatever you want within your talk() method, after you make a successful talkToSystem() call.

Oh, and what is "amount" doing here?

`this.amount = amount;`

Comment: yes, you are right. there is a method sets token. I didn't put it here.  For this.amount = amount, when a client constructs the MiddleMan, it passes in amount. There is an internal method validates amount.